# Android SQLite Error "requesting column name with table name"

Tags: android, sqlite

After running an sql query of the form:

```
SELECT table_name.column_name FROM table_name,table_name2,etc... WHERE condition1,condition2,etc...,
```

I get the following error, which does not shut down my program:

> requesting column name with table name -- table_name.column_name

A google search for this error phrase led me to [android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor line 314](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.6_r2/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteCursor.java)

A few lines above line 314 there is a comment that this code is a response to bug 903852. But I can't seem to find this bug on google.

So this is a two part question:

1. Is it wrong to name the column
   name with the table in SQL? (I was
   under the impression that this was a
   best practice)
2. How do I find
       Android bug report 903852 so that I
       can understand what the issue is?
       (googling Android bug 903852 doesn't
       work)

Comment: can you post your code please ?

Comment: Just to get you up and running: select a.column_name from table_name a where ... This does not answer your questions but should help you in case you are stuck.

Comment: See [AbstructCursor does not allow to use column name with period](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7201) for #2.

Answer (score 11):

In my case, the problem was solved when I used

```
select table_name.column_name as column_name_alt WHERE ....
```

and later, in my `CursorAdapter`, referred to it in the string array only as `column_name_alt`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good description of that problem and similar suggestion as in this reply: http://massimilianosciacco.com/sqlite-cursor-and-table-alias-bug-android-database

Answer (score 7):

So I ran into this problem while creating a `Cursor` that would be passed to a `SimpleCursorAdapter`.  Turns out that while it's OK to prefix your 'query' columns String[], the subsequent `String[] from` argument that's passed to the [`SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) does *not* need to be prefixed in order for the Adapter to map your result set correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same issue few days back and solved the issue using an alternative method. Previously I used the following method to set the cursor to point the column.

```
String sqlStatement = "SELECT supplierid,suppliercode,suppliername FROM supplierinfo WHERE suppliername  LIKE '%"+query+"%' ";
        cursor = db.rawQuery(sqlStatement,null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    int supplierId = cursor.getInt( 0);
                    String supplierCode = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( "suppliercode" )) != null ? cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( "suppliercode" ) ) : "";
                    String supplierName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( "suppliername" )) != null ? cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( "suppliername" ) ) : "";
                    supplierInfo =  new SupplierInfo();
                    supplierInfo.setSupplierID( supplierId );
                    supplierInfo.setSupplierCode( supplierCode );
                    supplierInfo.setSupplierName( supplierName );
                    supplierInfoList.add(supplierInfo);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
```

After I changed this into the following method it worked for me.

```
String sqlStatement = "SELECT supplierid,suppliercode,suppliername FROM supplierinfo WHERE suppliername  LIKE '%"+query+"%' ";
        cursor = db.rawQuery(sqlStatement,null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0){
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
                do {
                    int supplierId = cursor.getInt( 0);
                    String supplierCode = cursor.getString(1) != null ? cursor.getString( 1 ) : "";
                    String supplierName = cursor.getString(2) != null ? cursor.getString( 2 ) : "";
                    supplierInfo =  new SupplierInfo();
                    supplierInfo.setSupplierID( supplierId );
                    supplierInfo.setSupplierCode( supplierCode );
                    supplierInfo.setSupplierName( supplierName );
                    supplierInfoList.add(supplierInfo);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
```

Comment: For those who don't want to compare the two blocks of code word by word, the difference seems to be hard-coding the column index argument to `getString()` instead of using `getColumnIndex()`. That doesn't sound like the solution to the stated question.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the best practice is to surround all table names and condition values with single quotes! [I was getting 'unknown column name' errors in android even when the query worked in my stand-alone sqlite manager.]

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be related to the question. The OP isn't talking about an "unknown column name" error.